# using SafeConfigParser in Python

Tags: python

Sorry, I am new to Python here. I am trying to write a python script using SafeConfigParser module, read credentials from a file and perform a HTTP call. The below error is shown when running the script. How should I use variables "user" and "secret" in the key line (which calls base64 module).
Instead of running parser.get twice for user and secret, can this be done a better way?

```
import base64

from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

parser = SafeConfigParser()

parser.read('cred.ini')

user =  parser.get('test', 'username')

secret = parser.get('test', 'password')

print user

print secret

url = "https://192.168.1.1/list"

key = base64.b64encode(user):(secret)

print key
```

Credentials read

```
# cat cred.ini
[test]
username = james
password = mypass
```

Error:

```
 File "test.py", line 19
    key = base64.b64encode(user):(secret)
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.

```
key = base64.b64encode(user):(secret)
```

This is wrong

your have to try

```
key = base64.b64encode(user)
```

Comment: Tried the same but getting this error. TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `key = base64.b64encode(user):(secret)`?  

I think that you may want to make a base64 of <user>:<secret>, if so the call should be

`key = base64.b64encode(':'.join([user, secret]))`